# cert-manager no endpoints available for service "cert-manager-webhook"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I'm facing some issue even with the latest cert-manager (). I'm running on k8s v1.22 and the same chart was working as expected on v1.21
error:

```
Not ready: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": no endpoints available for service "cert-manager-webhook"
Not ready: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": no endpoints available for service "cert-manager-webhook"
```

This happens on the pod pod/cert-manager-startupapicheck-l4ccx started by job.batch/cert-manager-startupapicheck.

I am not sure why this is happening and how to fix this as it looks like to be a k8s issue rather than cert-manager.

Please can anyone point me to some documentation or some similar case as I was not able to find anything related to this. I read the documentation from cert-manager, all github issues I could find and this was not able to get this fixed.

Comment: I don't have this issue, but judging by the issue it seems like that the Service `cert-manager-webhook` has no endpoints. Can you check the configuration of this service and if the selectors specify a correct deployment? Because if the selectors were correct and the pods selected are up & running, you would see endpoint objects; unless it's and headless service which should not be the case here.

Comment: In my case I was going through a Kubernetes course on youtube and yesterday I shut down the working node to save money :) Starting it again solved my issue. Make sure you have worker nodes on your cluster

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because the `cert-manager-webhook` pod has not been provisioned yet (mine was due to maximum node reached, as I was in "eco-mode" with a very minimal desired-maximum node configuration in AWS EKS)

To investigate, you should check and verify if all the cert-manager pods is up and running correctly.

```
thang@Ivy aws-eks-playground % kubectl get pods -A | grep cert-manager
cert-manager     cert-manager-7564b796c7-9bwp2                   1/1     Running   0          29m
cert-manager     cert-manager-cainjector-58bcd74fd8-bcrbb        1/1     Running   0          29m
cert-manager     cert-manager-webhook-5bd9444ff7-rvql5           1/1     Running   0          29m
```

If any cert-manager pod fail, go ahead and describe it to figure out the problem and solve accordingly.

If the issue still occur, describe the `cert-manager-webhook` service to get the endpoint detail to troubleshoot thing further

```
$ kubectl get service -A
$ kubectl -n cert-manager describe service cert-manager-webhook
Name:              cert-manager-webhook
Namespace:         cert-manager
Labels:            app=webhook
                   app.kubernetes.io/component=webhook
                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=cert-manager
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=webhook
                   app.kubernetes.io/version=v1.5.4
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/component=webhook,app.kubernetes.io/instance=cert-manager,app.kubernetes.io/name=webhook
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.100.23.211
IPs:               10.100.23.211
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        10250/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.194.9:10250
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```